# Type deduction for template template parameters (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

With the code below I've got compiler error:

`type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp> class std::shared_ptr'
     std::shared_ptr<T> shared_pointer;
                      ^
../test/main.cpp:16:22: note:   expected a type, got 'T'`

Can't figure out why `T` is not properly deduced for `shared_pointer`?

```
template<typename K>
class Bar{
    K k;
};

template<template<typename> class T>
class Foo{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<T> shared_pointer;
};


int main(void)
{
    Foo<Bar<std::string>> foo;
}
```

**Update:**
Another example:

```
template<typename TObject, template<TObject> class TBuffer>
class BaseGrabber {

public:
    virtual void run(std::shared_ptr<TBuffer>){};
};
```

I want to force compiler error when someone write something like

```
BaseGrabber<int, Bar<long>> grabber;
```

so `Bar` never specialized with type that differs from first `BaseGrabber` template parameter.

Comment: What's the purpose of `template<typename>` in `template<template<typename> class T>`?

Comment: The error message is broken: that's a mismatch between the expected type, and the *template* that `T` is. IOW, `std::shared_ptr<T<something>>` would work.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius means (I suppose) that everything works just fine once you remove `template<typename>` and define Foo` as a `template<class T>`.

Comment: I'm using several template arguments and I want to force compiler error when someone tries instantiate template class with different template types. Updated question.

Comment: @AlanKazbekov Then you could use it as `BaseGrabber<int, Bar>`, and instantiate the template inside `BaseGrabber` with the template parameter `TObject`.

Comment: That is not the option. There is `run()`, that takes pointer to buffer as function argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

> [I] can't figure out why `T` is not properly deduced for `shared_pointer`?

```
template<template<typename> class T>
class Foo{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<T> shared_pointer;
};
```

---

**Answer:** `T` cannot be deduced for `shared_ptr` because `T` is a templated type, and you're not giving it any template arguments. Simply reduce it to `class T` and it will work:

```
template<class T>
class Foo{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<T> shared_pointer;
};
```

---

**Question 2:**

> I want to force compiler error when someone write something like:
>   `BaseGrabber<int, Bar<long>> grabber;`

**Answer:**
We shall write an empty primary specialization for `BaseGrabber`, and then specialize it for when the second argument uses the same template argument type as the first argument:

```
template<class T, class U>
class BaseGrabber{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "Template argument is not correct");
};

template<class T, template<class> class U>
class BaseGrabber<T, U<T>> {
public:
    virtual void run(std::shared_ptr<T>){};
}
```

Test it like so:

```
int main()
{
    Foo<Bar<std::string>> foo;
    //BaseGrabber<int, Bar<long>> grabber; // compiler error
    BaseGrabber<int, Bar<int>> grabber;
}
```

#### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pNoUUUuo1jFwyGRw)

Comment: Thanks for #1 and thanks for #2! Just discovered `static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "...");` for myself as a common practice!